# Allow users to download a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read through a number of StackOverflow threads and tutorials, and I haven't found a **good, simple explanation** for how to allow a user to download a file from your site.

All I want to do is add a link to one of my views which downloads a file when clicked.

I'd like to understand:

- Where do I store the downloadable file in my file system? `public`?
- Is there anything special about linking to the file in your view, or it's just a `link_to`?
- What needs to happen in `routes`? It's just a `get` for that `controller#action`?
- What needs to happen in the controller? In rails documentation I've read that you need to "be careful to sanitize the path parameter if it is coming from a web page," but I'm not sure exactly what that means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple scenario, you don't need controller to download file. Just save file to `public` folder. Public folder is default folder for static resources there are stored compiled js, css, images files, robot.txt and so on.

If you have file `monthly-report.doc`. Put it to `public/reports/monthly-report.doc`.

In view `link_to 'Donwload Report', '/reports/monthly-report.doc'`

Comment: Thank you! (have to meet the character minimum)

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two cases:

### 1. The file is public and should be downloadable by anyone.

Place it in the `/public` directory. Remember that this is the web root - so if you have a file that lives at `/public/foo/bar.baz` you would link to the file with `<%= link_to 'A file', '/foo/bar.baz' %>`.

No routes or controllers are need since we are just serving a static file from the servers public directory.

### 2. The file needs access control

In this example we are dynamically servering files stored in `/downloads`.

```
# routes.rb
resources :downloads, only: [:show]

class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  # do your authentication logic here

  # GET /downloads/:id
  # @example
  #  GET /downloads/foo.bar would download a file stored at
  #  /downloads/foo.bar
  # @raise [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound] if the file does not exist.
  #   This causes a 404 page to be rendered.
  def show
    fn = Rails.root.join('downloads', params[:id])
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and return unless file.exists?(fn) 
    send_file(fn)
  end
end
```

By using Rails to serve the download we can apply whatever access control rules we want.

Answer (score 0):

The `link_to` is the same as any other link.

If you want to store it in public then do this in whatever controller action you want.

```
send_file File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'file.extension')
```

You could create a downloads controller and specify that in the index then simply `link_to 'Download', download_index_path` or such.

If you're trying to send a file name that a user inputs, you have to sanitize it. If it's "hard coded" like the above example, then you're fine.